# rails display all posts with current category id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to display posts that have a :cat_id of current category and I'm not clicking the right things together I'm guessing. Let me explain;

Each post has a cat_id in DB, it will be the ID of the category. On my page, if I click on a category the url changes to something like; http://domain.com/cat/1 and it should display all posts category 1 has.

So far I've tried the following with no success;

**CONTROLLER**

```
def show
    @cat = Cat.find(params[:id])
    @cat = Cat.all
    @posts = @cat.posts
end
```

**VIEW**

```
<div id="posts">
<% @posts.limit(50).each do |post| %>
    <h1><%= post.title %></h1>
<% end %>
</div>
```

No success with the above.

I've also tried;

**CONTROLLER**

```
def show
    @cat = Cat.find(params[:id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

**VIEW**

```
<div id="posts">
<% @bin.posts(:cat_id => cat.id).limit(50).each do |post| %>
    <h1><%= post.title %></h1>
<% end %>
</div>
```

No luck either. I know I'm close, just can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, all I did was remove the overwriting of `@cat` with `Cat.all` and move the post limit to the controller with the rest of the query:

**CONTROLLER**

```
def show
    @cat = Cat.find(params[:id])
    @posts = @cat.posts.limit(50)
end
```

**VIEW**

```
<div id="posts">
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <h1><%= post.title %></h1>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried that and I'm getting # undefined method `posts' for #<Class:0x007f34ff635728>

Comment: Can you post the full backtrace at somewhere like http://pastie.org/ and provide a link to it here so I can see more of what is going on?

Comment: I did however do this; `def show @cat = Cat.find(params[:id]) @posts = Posts.where(:bin_id => params[:id])` which seemed to work. I know that might be quite ugly but I'm so new to rails.

Comment: That is a bit ugly, can you provide your Cat and Post models in the original question so that I can see why you are having to find the posts manually?

Comment: Never mind, I've got it. Had `@cats.posts` in my code rather then `@cat.posts`. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, glad you solved your problem. Have fun learning more Rails!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you that you are using a proper model association.

If you have setup your model so that a post belongs to a category and a category has many posts like this:

Post Model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :cat
end
```

Cat Model:

```
class Cat < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :posts
end
```

Then you just need to use that association like this:

Controller:

```
def show
  @cat = Cat.find(params[:id])
  @posts = @cat.posts
end
```

View:

```
<div id="posts">
  <% for post in @posts do %>
    <h1><%= post.title %></h1>
  <%end%>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, figured it out as it works with JVP code, yours is exactly the same. :) Thanks for the help.

Comment: I guess I got beat to the punch :)